# Probability and Combinatorics (samples)

Tags: combinatorics

> There are only $10$ polar bears left in the wilderness and they are slowly dying of starvation. We know for certain that 4 of them are pregnant, the rest are either male or not pregnant. We wish to save as many of the pregnant mother bears as possible. However, the high cost of search and rescue only allows us to catch randomly $5$ of these $10$ bears in the wilderness.
>
> Find the probability that at least $1$ pregnant mother bear is caught in this sample of $5$ bears.

My idea is that by finding the combination of arranging the 10 bears into the sample, this can be used to calculate the probability. For example, this would be $_{10}C_{5} = 30240$. However, how would I calculate the number of arrangements of the four bears that will go into the sample? I considered $_{5}C_{4}$, yet this would be illogical as it only includes the number of arrangements of the four bears in the sample, but does not consider the arrangements in the sample not selected. Is my working correct?

Comment: As is often the case, it is easier to work backwards.  What is the probability that the five you select do *not* include any pregnant mothers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is correct. You will need $_{10}C_5$, as this is the total number of combinations of picking 5 bears out of 10. But the second part starts to go awry. We are not interested in $_5C_{\text{anything}}$ because it looks like the 5 is referring to what you already selected. This is generally not the way to go. Instead, you need to find the probability that 1 pregnant mother is in the sample, 2, 3, or all 4. This is $\frac{_4C_1*_6C_4+_4C_2*_6C_3+_4C_3*_6C_2+_4C_4*_6C_1}{_{10}C_5}$, where each term in the numerator represents choosing however many pregnant mother bears times choosing however many male or not pregnant mother bears. Divide this all by the number of ways to choose 5 bears out of 10.

It is easier to think of the complement, one minus the probability of selecting no pregnant mother bears. $1-\frac{_6C_5}{_{10}C_5}$. This is the same as adding up all the terms above.